# Can I relight my hardware keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, htc-chacha

I have an HTC chacha with a hardware keyboard.  A nighttime reading app turned off the keyboard light  long ago, but I don't remember which of the hundreds available it was.  Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Please read the [FAQ] under this title **What about other Android-related questions?**, specifically this: *Recommendations, like "Which phone is better?" or "Can you suggest an app that does X?"*

Comment: I'm trying to solve an error or other issue with my android device.  I am not asking for a suggestion for an app.  I am asking a practical, answerable questions based on an actual problem I am facing.

Comment: Your best bet is to get the same app or another and undo it.  Most likely the driver was moved or disabled, unless your kernel supports settings to disable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download this app from the Google Play Store, called [Soft Buttons Light](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meco.sbl&hl=en).

It really works, even on HTC Chacha.

Comment: You have fixed a problem I've been putting up with for *months*.